# Cant connect to Office365 SMTP via PHPmailer

Tags: php, smtp, office365, phpmailer

i have problem to connect through smtp to office365. I read all tips here but nothing help.

***Debug:***

```
2018-05-16 08:12:52   Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   Connection: opened 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 CWLP265CA0229.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 16 May 2018 08:12:52 +0000 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-CWLP265CA0229.outlook.office365.com Hello [109.81.243.32] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-CWLP265CA0229.outlook.office365.com Hello [109.81.243.32] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx== 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2018-05-16 08:12:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx= 
2018-05-16 08:12:58   SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [CWLP265CA0229.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 
2018-05-16 08:12:58   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [CWLP265CA0229.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 
2018-05-16 08:12:58   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2018-05-16 08:12:58   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2018-05-16 08:12:58   SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel 
2018-05-16 08:12:58   Connection: closed 
2018-05-16 08:12:58   SMTP connect() failed.
```

***PHP CODE:***

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'MAIL@DOMAIN.TLD'; 
$mail->Password = 'PASS';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('MAIL@DOMAIN.TLD');
$mail->addAddress('TOMAIL'); // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Isn't this quite descriptive? _"Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful"_

Comment: But credentials are ok. What with this?

Comment: Apparently they are not. I just tried your code with my old hotmail address and it worked like a charm. If you're 100% sure that the credentials are correct, then are you sure that the from address is hosted on Office365?

Comment: Yes. I just logged in with this credentials to web mail on https://login.microsoftonline.com/

Comment: Well, I can confirm that the above code works. If you have the correct credentials and the from address is hosted on Office365 but still doesn't work, you need to contact Microsoft.

Comment: You can also check this issue on github for PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1339 - Seems like Office 365's SMTP is a bit wonky.

Comment: Your password was included in your debug output (which also tells me you're using an old version of PHPMailer). I've edited it out, but I'd recommend changing it.

Answer (score 4):

### You have to enable it in o365 admin panel, then wait 3 minutes and done

> also check **$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;**

[image]

Use the Microsoft 365 admin center to enable or disable SMTP AUTH on specific mailboxes

> ```
> Open the Microsoft 365 admin center and go to Users > Active users.
>
> Select the user, and in the flyout that appears, click Mail.
>
> In the Email apps section, click Manage email apps.
>
> Verify the Authenticated SMTP setting: unchecked = disabled, checked = enabled.
>
> When you're finished, click Save changes.
> ```